# Multiple contexts with Entity Framework 6, reference entities across dbcontexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am writing two MVC5 (with EF6 and code-first) web apps using generic UnitOfWork that gets the dbContext injected by Unity.

We are required to have two databases (Main Database and Project Specific DB) and have a reference between the two.

Here's an example:

- in the main context I have an entity `Employee`
- in the project context I have an entity `Department`

I need to create Departments in my Project that group and organize Employees from Main.

Can I have...

`ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }` in the Project DB's `Department` Entity ? (the relationship between Employees and Departments is many-to-many)

How would you go about having something like this done ?

Comment: I don't think the DbContexts themselves are going to handle this, so there will likely be some manual work behind the abstraction.  An EF-ignored property on `Department` could internally fetch the collection of `Employee`s from the other context, though tracking changes to them could get difficult.  You may need to choose a "primary" context as your unit of work and abstract the other one behind it, manually checking for updates to the other context's entities when you commit changes to the primary context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to link tables from one database to the other so that this is the database server which handles two physical databases as one virtual database.

Then, in EF, you have just one context with tables from both databases and querying/joins etc. works correctly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Otherwise, linking two databases in the application layer with EF and two contexts sounds impossible.

Comment: True, EF (at the moment) doesn't support creating a query which uses more than one context.

Comment: And SQL Server is quite good at linking between databases or even other servers.

Comment: @WiktorZychla After linking two databases, need I create Views in order to use one DbContext in EF? How to declare the DbContext that works with Views?